# Best approximation rates of various classes of functions by truncated Fourier series

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, approximation-theory

Let $f\in C([-1,1]^d)$ have periodic boundary, $N$ be a positive integer, and let $S_N(f)$ be the best approximation of $f$ by its truncated Fourier expansion truncated approximation
$$
S_N(f):=\sum_{n=-N}^N \hat{f}(n) e^{int}.
$$
In the case where $f\in C^{r,1}([-1,1]^d)$, we know the *uniform* rate of convergence of
$$
\|f-S_N(f)\|_{L^{\infty}([-1,1]^d)} \lesssim \frac{\log(N)^d}{N^r}.
$$
My question is, if $f$ instead belongs to either of the following classes:

- $f$ is analytic,
- $f$ is smooth,
- $f$ is bandlimited,
- $f$ is Besov $B^s_{p,q}([-1,1]^d)$ for $s>0$ and $p,q\in [1,\infty]$.

Then are there known rates?  Most importantly, where can one find such rates?